# uploading a media asset failed in broadleaf-ADMIN

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

Hi I am getting this Error When I Try Upload a Media asset Please help to solve the Error

Here is the Screen Shot link for the Error:

http://i.prntscr.com/0ZhZ3IYaQ4qQ2CTjH7YUVQ.png

Here is the Server Log:

http://i.prntscr.com/RpiHm_HyTRGtrKuAR3B8tg.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the Java agent at `Eclipse -> Run Configurations -> Arguments -> vmargument` and add one of the following depending on your operating system:

If you use Ubuntu:

```
-javaagent:"/root/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-instrument-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar"
```

If you use Windows:

```
-javaagent:"/C:/USERS/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-instrument/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-instrument-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar"
```